# create a file through a variable in bash

Tags: bash, date, filenames

I have this issue with a simple bash script to create a file and then log to it the output of rsync.

However, it does not work I keep getting "command not found", does not create the file and does not log to it. I get the error "/var/log/" is a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=ram_sys4-$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M).log
touch /var/log/$(FILENAME)
date >> /var/log/$(FILENAME)
rsync -r -L -H -g -o -p -t -a --delete --verbose --log-format="%t %i %l %f %M %h %o \n" --log-file=/var/log/$(FILENAME) /root/Desktop/R/ /root/Desktop/W/
date >> /var/log/$(FILENAME)
```

Comment: Instead of `$(FILENAME)` use `${FILENAME}`

Comment: Please do not answer questions with a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `$(VAR_NAME)` is used in Makefiles, but not in bash. In bash, use

```
${VAR_NAME}
```

or even simpler

```
$VAR_NAME
```

Comment: if my filename has date + hour & minute, the next time the script calls the filename, for example during the .tar command, will it tar the same file or attempt to tar a new one? Because, the hour or minute has probably changed since the rsync task started

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=ram_sys4-$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M).log
touch /var/log/${FILENAME}
date >> /var/log/${FILENAME}
rsync -r -L -H -g -o -p -t -a --delete --verbose --log-format="%t %i %l %f %M %h %o \n" --log-file=/var/log/${FILENAME} /root/Desktop/R/ /root/Desktop/W/
date >> /var/log/${FILENAME}
```

`$(FILENAME)` is [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) what you are trying do to is [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)